# Onenote pages created via Microsoft graph shows as unread (with green color) in the OneNote client

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

This is not the correct behavior in my mind. It should behave the same way as if the page was created via the OneNote client. This behavior creates a big usability issue for our end users since the whole page will be covered with the green color of changes in the page.

**Request**

```
POST 
graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupid}/onenote/sections/{sectionid}/pages
HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/html
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
request-id, client-request-id
```

**Screenshot of the OneNote client**

[image: Click here to see screenshot]

Comment: This really isn't a question. If you're looking for a change to the API, I would suggest using the UserVoice site: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis

Comment: Okey. I'll post this on UserVoice. Thanks for reply.